# BatchGet - AWS DynamoDB with any sort key

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS (JS) Document Client library for DynamoDb and trying to do a `batchGet` from a table (partition+sort key). Issue is that I would like to get all items by partition key and any sort key.

If I don't define sort key in `batchGet` I get `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`.
If I do - it works fine but is really inconvenient for me, and I can query same table by only partition key so I think I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating multiple Global Secondary Indexes (GSIs) using partition key and the multiple sort keys that you need for your application.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html for reference.

Hope this helps!